# How to connect JetBrains Xodus to S3?

Tags: java, xodus

For JetBrains Xodus database,

Is there a way to connect it to Amazon S3 or S3-compatible storage instead of local file system?

Not sure if this is related but I can see hints of S3 from https://github.com/JetBrains/xodus/tree/master/multinode/src/main/kotlin/jetbrains/exodus/entitystore/replication

Comment: This is just a piece of code in master, it's not released/documented.